# LX games session?

Tags: lubuntu, games, session

I am running lubuntu 13.10, and I have discovered a new session named "LX games". when I run it, i can only see my desktop and cairo-dock(which i added to autostart). Can sombody tell me what LX games is for and how to configure it? I havent found anything useful yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/lubuntu-users/2013-May/004245.html

"It's a session with a menu structure with only games categories"